# Adding an Activity Indicator Programmatically to a View

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview, uiapplicationdelegate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show activity indicator during application launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849072/show-activity-indicator-during-application-launch)

All,

Inside my app delegate, I created an animated splash view that uses my Default.png. That all works OK but I cannot figure out how get my ActivityIndicator to display on top of the splash view. It's there just hidden by the splash view. Here is what I have and thanks:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 //... data access stuff here ...

 self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

// ... more setup stuff here ...



/****************************************************************************
 *
 *
 * Splash Screen for iPhone
 *
 ****************************************************************************/
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {


    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    [self.window addSubview:splashView];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
    splashView.alpha = 0.0;
    splashView.frame = CGRectMake(-60, -60, 440, 600);
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    //Create and add the Activity Indicator to splashView
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0;
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
    [splashView addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];



}


  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For all those who needed this, and i know there were many...
(Made on Xcode version 4.2.1)

So...

In the AppDelegate.h add this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *splashView;
```

In the AppDelegate.m add this:

On the top of the page of cours @synthesize splashView;
And then:

```
- (void) splashFade
{
    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    [_window addSubview:splashView];
    [_window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:2.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:_window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
    splashView.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    //Create and add the Activity Indicator to splashView
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0;
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 360);
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
    [splashView addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

The **[UIView setAnimationDelay:2.5]** is responsible for how long the splashView will be in front by the delay time you choose.

You can change the position of the indicator by changing the nubmers of x/y in:
**activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 360);**

At last, under the methode:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Just add this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(splashFade) withObject:nil];
```

And there you go :)
Hope it helped.

Have a nice programming....

Comment: Hi what should the parameter in the (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context

Comment: hidesWhenStopped = NO was key for me, otherwise it would be hidden no matter what

Answer (score 0):

Seems you hiding (alpha -> 0.0) your splashView in 0.5sec. What you should see in this case?

Comment: Yep, that just gives me a nice transition from splashView to the main view. When I comment it out, I still get the same result - The ActivityIndicator is hidden behind the splashView

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
[splashView bringSubviewToFront:activityIndicator];
```

Comment: Yep. Get the same result. The problem may be that splashView is a UIImageView. I heard that sometimes putting subViews on top of UIImageViews doesn't work