# UIAlertview not closing properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using a `UIAlertview` and inside that one activity indicator in `viewdidload()`  .But i tried to remove its from superview after a delay but after removing `UIAlertview` using following code i am not able to do anything in app.Is like a new transparent layer is still running above my view.

**CODE**

```
 -(void)startAlertActivity
    {
        _alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading "
                                                message:@"\n"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

        spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

        spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5); // .5 so it doesn't blur
        [_alertView addSubview:spinner];

        [spinner startAnimating];
        [_alertView show];
        [_alertView performSelector:@selector(stopAlertActivity) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];


    }

    -(void)stopAlertActivity
    {  [spinner stopAnimating];
        [_alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }
```

ITS look like a transparent layer still running on screen,How can i close that?

**example image....**
[image]

**for me that alert is not in screen now  but the background is there in light blue color**

**CRASH REPORT**

```
[UIAlertView stopAlertActivity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ab5eb0
2013-08-02 12:20:43.822 AssamKart[5719:12203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIAlertView stopAlertActivity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ab5eb0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: are you using any third party control ?

Comment: nop.iam using  just alertview and indicator

Comment: Issue is with `[_alertView performSelector:@selector(stopAlertActivity) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];
` change that to: `[self performSelector:@selector(stopAlertActivity) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should really be using dispatch_after

```
_alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading "
                                        message:@"\n"
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5); // .5 so it doesn't blur
[_alertView addSubview:spinner];

[spinner startAnimating];
[_alertView show];



double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [_alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line:

```
[_alertView performSelector:@selector(stopAlertActivity) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];
```

to:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stopAlertActivity) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

The `stopAlertActivity` method is a method of `self`, not the alert view. And you can't pass an object to the selector because `stopAlertActivity` does not take any parameters.

Comment: That can't be. Did you change `_alertView` to `self` like I did?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dismiss the `alertView` by removing it from its superView. Instead you have to call `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`. This is the only way to dismiss it correctly, see the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html).
In your case, I would define a method with the `alertView` as argument that executes `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`, and perform this method after the delay.

Answer (score 0):

You should dismiss the alert view, not remove from superview, because it is attached to a semi transparent background. Call `stopAlertActivity` after the delay.

Comment: but i tried to call another method with delay 5.0 and inside that new method iam trying to dismiss at that time its crashing

Comment: You should call not on the alerview but on self. the method you need to call is not declared in UIAlertView, but in the class si diplaying it