# Animated UIActivityIndicatorView on LaunchScreen.xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

With the new xcode one is able to present a .xib named `LaunchScreen` on launch, which is great. I added a `UIActivityIndicator` to this very file, but I am not able to animate it. How can I accomplish this? Do I need to add a code file just for this?

**What I've tried**

- Selected 'Animating' in the 'behavior' section of the xib

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27519797/4525866

Comment: thanks @RomanSalabay! however, I am able to add it to the launch screen, and it's visible, it's just not animating. is this .xib not intended to be used for animations then? i see that answer suggests to utilize a code-based approach.

Comment: Animation is disabled on LaunchScreen. Therefore you need to use workaround.

Comment: gotcha! ok, thanks will look into it.

Comment: main thread is busy doing app start.. it will not animate that easily.